# facebook javascript api call returning undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm having trouble with the javascript sdk for Facebook. I'm trying to do a simple api call which returns my name, according to the documentation. An alert should popup stating "Your name is ", but I'm getting "Your name is undefined" instead. Am I missing something?

The php SDK is working well, so I know it's not an error regarding app setup. I'm also currently logged into the app.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<app id>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());


</script>
```

Comment: Do `console.log(response);` before the alert in the callback and see what the response actually contains.

Comment: thanks James, I get 
code: 2500
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"

is there a way to get the token? I am logged in already.

Comment: i've also run FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') { console.log('connected'); }} and i get connected in the log.